# optional class constructor properties based on class generic type

Tags: typescript

i have a base class that uses generics. the class looks like the following

```
class Base<T extends Record<keyof T, unknown> | undefined = undefined> {

  constructor(a: number, b: () => T) {
    
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make `b` optional so that i don't have to write `super(6, undefined)` when i intend for it to be `undefined`.

With normal functions this can be done easily.

```
function f<T extends undefined>(a: number, b?: () => T): void;
function f<T extends Record<keyof T, unknown>>(a: number, b: () => T): void;
function f<T extends Record<keyof T, unknown> | undefined>(a: number, b?: () => T): void {

}
```

Comment: `constructor(a: number, b?: T) {`?

Comment: @zerkms I only want it be optional when T is undefined

Comment: what is the point of the generic in that case T is undefined? that doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Daniel A. White oh ```T``` is used as a member variable and is returned by other member functions in the class. my example does not show this sorry

Comment: yea but it doesn't make sense to have a member variable that is always `undefined`. something is fishy with your abstraction

Comment: so this example was super simplified my real world example is different. in my code i am actually passing a callback where ```T``` is the returned value. trust me it better then it sounds =)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the typescript Partial type?

With it you can define a constructor where you can insert just what you want, when you want it. Handle the details in the constructor method.

I'm not even going to pretend I follow your type definition for Base T. However, if you want to create objects without just some params, Partial is the way to go.

```
class Base<T> {

  constructor(init?: Partial<Base<T>) {
    
  }

  prop1 : string;
  prop2 : string;
}

// You'd use it like this, note that only one property is being set.

var thing = new Base<T>({ prop1: "stuff" });
```

Here is a blogpost that explains it in detail.
https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-partial-type-in-typescript-ecfcfbc87cb6